# Quicksight, CSP & embed URL

Tags: embed, content-security-policy, amazon-quicksight

I created a dashboard using Quicksight service. I embed the url using `generateEmbedUrlForRegisteredUser`

On the frontend(React app), I use amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk package to embed the url.

If I click the url,it opens my dashboard but on my application i have this error

```
Refused to frame 'https://{myzone}.quicksight.aws.amazon.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".
```

My helmet rules are:

```
const hemetRules= {
 crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,
  crossOriginResourcePolicy: false,
  crossOriginOpenerPolicy: false,
  xFrameOptions: false,
 contentSecurityPolicy: {
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: [self],
      connectSrc: [
  frameAncestors: [ 'self']
.......more
}
}
```

Do you have any idea about what is happening here? I'm blocked.

Thanks in advance

I tried to update the frameAncestor with:

frameAncestors: [
self,
'http://localhost:3000',
'https://eu-west-2.quicksight.aws.amazon.com/',
],

This is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error. I fixed it by adding the domain where the react app was being hosted in the `Domains and Embedding` [link the AWS Quicksight.](https://eu-west-2.quicksight.aws.amazon.com/sn/admin#embedding)

You also need to make sure the region of the dashboard is the same as the Quicksight console you are accessing.

I made a mistake adding a domain in `us-east-1` not knowing that the dashboard was created on `ap-southeast-2`. Hope this helps!